# Approximate implementation of GeoDestination

Tags: geodesy

I need an implementation to approximate GeoDestination without an internet connection. This is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid) which says:
[image: two main problems]
I need to solve "1. the direct geodesic problem".
Later that article says:
[image: a solution]
That says handling the direct problem is straight forward. How do we do that step that is straight forward?

Comment: Does GeoDestination actually require an internet connection? My impression was that it did exactly the calculations you reference.

Comment: Indeed, GeoDestination does not require an internet connection with numeric input. Only with Entity inputs we need to connect to WolframAlpha to download {lat, lon} information. GeoDestination (for the direct geodesic problem) and GeoDistance/GeoDirection/GeoDisplacement (for the inverse geodesic problem) implement the algorithms by Karney (2013), as described in that wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

I verified that the comments are correct, and an internet connection is not required. I must have been confused.